# Finding the UI element in protractor is not consistent. Working with localhost and not with the server

Tags: javascript, protractor

Here is the code I am using `expect(element(by.id('title')).getAttribute('value')).toMatch('Sample Title')`

in local machine it is working perfectly fine and on server it is not with the following error.

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="title"])
```

and surprisingly sometimes these tests are working on server when I execute them alone.

to add to the question. I observed that protractor is able to find only one element in the tests and all the remaining are ignored with the error as above.

what could be the solution for this?

Comment: You should debug what is happening in the browser at this particular point in the test. It could that it's just that you need to give it more time and adjust the [`allScriptsTimeout` setting](http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts#timeouts-from-protractor).

Comment: I did that increased it to 60 sec, still the same. Its failing with the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

That could be application issue. Sometimes it happens that angular never reports to protractor that all tasks are done, so you might get this timeout error that you have.

http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

> AngularJS If your AngularJS application continuously polls $timeout or
>   $http, Protractor will wait indefinitely and time out. You should use
>   the $interval for anything that polls continuously (introduced in
>   Angular 1.2rc3).
>
> Angular For Angular apps, Protractor will wait until the Angular Zone
>   stabilizes. This means long running async operations will block your
>   test from continuing. To work around this, run these tasks outside the
>   Angular zone. For example:
>
> this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {   setTimeout(() => {
>       // Changes here will not propagate into your view.
>       this.ngZone.run(() => {
>         // Run inside the ngZone to trigger change detection.
>       });   }, REALLY_LONG_DELAY); }); As an alternative to either of these options, you could disable waiting for Angular, see below.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried all the possible timeout options but nothing worked out.

Answer (score -1):

As said in the error, it seems your app is not an angular. Isn't it?

If so, you need to use it:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input... but i cannot use that.. protractor is not waiting for the angular when it is actually needed if i use this command...